# Starting a build number from a specific number

Tags: azure-devops, azure-yaml-pipelines

I just migrated some builds from bamboo over to azure devops and I need to get the build numbers in ado to start from a specific number, for example last build in bamboo was 50, I need the first build in ado to be 51.  How can I accomplish this via yaml pipeline?

Can I do someting like name: $(last.bamboo.build)+$(Rev:r)?

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have simple number versioning and continue it from certain number you can do it like this:

```yaml
name: $(Rev:r)

steps:
- script: echo '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
- pwsh: |
    $buildId = 50 + $(Build.BuildNumber)
    Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$buildId"
- script: echo '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

Answer (score 1):

To further elaborate on @Krzysztof's answer, the `name` property determines the build-number format, but this can be changed at run-time by updating the `updatebuildnumber` variable as shown.

According to the screenshot in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57508818/6817821), this will actually update the pipeline run name as well.